# How to fix %!(EXTRA int=3) error in Golang?

Tags: go, int, extra

I'm quite new to Golang and I'd like to know why this error keeps coming out every time i run the code

**%!(EXTRA int=3)**

```
...
var money int
var buyItem string
fmt.Print("Inserisci il nome dell'arma che vuoi comprare: ")
fmt.Scan(&buyItem)
switch buyItem {
        case "Racchetta":
            fmt.Println("Hai comprato con successo la racchetta")
            money = money - 1
            fmt.Printf("Soldi rimanenti:", money)
        case "Granata":
            fmt.Println("Hai comprato con successo la granata")
            money = money - 7
            fmt.Printf("Soldi rimanenti:", money)
        case "AK":
            fmt.Println("Hai comprato con successo l'AK")
            money = money - 12
            fmt.Printf("Soldi rimanenti:", money)
        default:
            fmt.Println("Non hai inserito il nome dell'arma corretto")
}
```

When I run it,I get this error: Soldi rimanenti:%!(EXTRA int=3)
Can anyone help me?

Comment: There is  a difference between Print**f** and Print**ln**. Consult the documentation.

Comment: Yeah I know the difference, I was distracted and I forgot that Printf needs %v, %d or %f etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add formatters to your string, *e.g.*

```golang
fmt.Printf("Soldi rimanenti: %v\n", money)
```

`%v` is a general formatter, good for most cases, but more exists. Check out examples here https://gobyexample.com/string-formatting

`\n` is for adding line return after the print.

Comment: oh thanks very much, I forgot about it <3